# Proving equality of homology of a product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'd like to prove the following equality:
$$H_i(X \times S^{n}) = H_i(X) \times H_{i-n}(X) $$

For $n=0$ it's pretty obvious, hence I'll use induction.Dividing $S^{n}$ into two hemipsheres $D^{n}_1,D^{n}_2$ and taking $A = X \times D^{n}_1,B =X \times D^{n}_2, A \cap B = X \times S^{n-1} $, I get an exact sequence (From Meyer Vietoris sequence):
$$\rightarrow H_{i}(X \times S^{n-1}) \rightarrow H_i(X) \times H_i(X) \rightarrow H_i(X \times S^{n}) \rightarrow H_{i-1}(X \times S^{n-1})\rightarrow H_{i-1}(X) \times H_{i-1}(X) $$
From induction: $$H_{i-1}(X \times S^{n-1}) \cong H_{i-1}(X) \times H{[i-1-n +1]} (X) $$

We get the sequence:
$$*0 \rightarrow {e} \times H_i(X) \rightarrow H_{i}(X \times S^{n}),\phi:\rightarrow H_{i-n}(X) \rightarrow 0 $$
Where the second arrow comes from inculusion ${e} \times H_i(X) \subset H_i(X) \times H_i(X)$ and the homomorphism is induced by the upper diagram.The arrow $\phi$ comes from the composition:
$$H_i(X \times S^{n}) \rightarrow H_{i-1}(X) \times H_{[i-1 -n +1]}(X) \rightarrow H_{[i-1 -n +1]}(X)$$
The first arrow comes from the first diagram, while the second arrow comes from the projection.
Since $X \times S^{n} $ retracts onto $X \times {p_0}$, it would be enough to prove the sequence $*$ is exact.And wihile it's true for the first two arrows, I am not able to prove the same for arrow $\phi$.Is it even true? Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Can't you just use the Kunneth theorem?

Comment: I don't know it.I quess it is not an easy one.

Comment: This follows at once from the Künneth formula, if you have that at your disposal. There is however also a more elementary proof. I did exactly that computation here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508837/what-is-h-sm-times-sn-without-using-k%C3%BCnneth-theorem/1509204#1509204

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already managed to do it your way a few days ago (thanks to a hint in Hatcher), nevertheless I'd love to do it my way- so let me ask a slightly different question:
Once we know $$H_i(X \times S^n)=H_i(X) \times H_{i-n}(X)$$ is it possible to prove that embedding $r:X \rightarrow X \times S^{n} $ sends $H_i(X) $ exactly to $H_i(X)$ (in $H_i(X) \times H_{i-n}$)?

Answer (score 1):

By the [Kunneth theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem), $$H_i(X\times S^n) \cong \bigoplus_{j+k=i} H_j(X)\otimes H_k(S^n)$$ This is because the Tor term in the short exact sequence vanishes because $H_k(S^n)$ is always a free abelian group. Since $H_k(S^n) = 0$ when $k \neq 0, n$, it follows that $$H_i(X\times S^n) \cong (H_i(X)\otimes H_0(S^n)) \oplus (H_{i-n}(X) \otimes H_n(S^n)) \cong H_i(X) \oplus H_{i-n}(X)$$